# googletrans restarting a for loop after 50 elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translate, google-translation-api

I need a loop to restart because I'm limited as to how many elements I can process before google blocks me using googletrans module.

I've worked out that I can get about fifty elements using a random time delay until Google blocks me but I need it to loop through about 850.

As far as I know there is no way to restart a loop so I tried a while loop but it doesn't seen to update the loop and finishes after the first block has been processed.

I am also randomly setting a second interval between between translations to keep the loop working. it goes from 0 to 50 and then stops the loops

my code

```
from googletrans import Translator
from random import randint
import datetime

should_restart = True
spanish_subs = get_subs(page)# list of over 850 sentances to be translated
counter_num = 1   
translator = Translator()
start_block = 0
end_block = 50

while should_restart:

print('start_block ' + str(start_block))# see where the loop is in the process
print('end_block  ' + str(end_block))

if end_block < len(get_subs(page)):
  translations = translator.translate(spanish_subs[start_block:end_block], src='es')    

  for translation in translations:           
      english_subs.append(translation.text)
      print('Loop ' + str(counter_num + 1 ))
      time.sleep(random())# pauses between 1 and 10 seconds

if end_block >= len(get_subs(page)):
  should_restart = False

  with open('englist_translation.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in english_subs:
      f.write("%s\n" % item)
      print('Finished')


start_block = end_block + 50
end_block = end_block + 50 # date the end block
print(english_subs)# print to console to see what was translated
return english_subs

def random():
  random_number = randint(0, 10)
  return random_number
```

Answer (score 0):

This setup will help you get past Googles limits, it is a slow process but it works on a list of 50,000 characters.

```
from random import randint
import time
from googletrans import Translator


def get_script_eng():

    should_restart = True
    spanish_subs = get_subs(page)  

    counter_num = 1   
    translator = Translator()
    start_block = 0
    end_block = 50

    while end_block < len(get_subs(page)):


    print('start_block ' + str(start_block))
    print('end_block  ' + str(end_block))

    if should_restart  == True:
      translations = translator.translate(spanish_subs[start_block:end_block], src='es')

      for translation in translations:           
        english_subs.append(translation.text)
        time.sleep(random()) 
      print('translation ' + str(counter_num + 1 ))

    else:
      should_restart = False
      with open('spanish.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in english_subs:
          f.write("%s\n" % item)
          print('Finished')
    start_block = start_block + 50
    end_block = end_block + 50
    print(english_subs)
  return english_subs
```

And then to generate the random time delay

```
def random():
  random_number = randint(0, 10)
  return random_number
```